# Load Tinymce at last edit position

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to load a saved Tinymce document at the line/caret position where the document was last saved. I've looked at the [BookmarManager](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.dom.bookmarkmanager/)

This explains simply that "This class handles selection bookmarks." So I'm not sure if this is a solution to opening the document at the last edit point.

Any help or direction is much appreciated.